# Playing MP3's java

Tags: java, mp3

I'm trying to play an MP3 file, on my desktop. I've got something atm which plays the MP3 but I can't adjust the volume. Even though it should work according to the docs.  My code:

I use this: https://code.google.com/p/java-audio-player/

```
import maryb.player.Player;

public class MusicPlayer {

    private Player player;
    private float volume;
    private String filePath;

    /**
     * Gets the location of the file being played.
     * @return
     */
    public String getFileLocation() {
        return filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the volume at which the music file is being played.
     * @return
     */
    public float getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current volume of the music file being played.
     * @param volume
     */
    public void setVolume(float volume) {
        this.player.setCurrentVolume(volume);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new MusicPlayer object, to use the specified music file.
     * @param filePath - path to the music file.
     * @param volume - volume the file should be played at.
     */
    public MusicPlayer(String filePath, float volume) {
        try {
            player = new Player();
            player.setCurrentVolume(volume);
            player.setSourceLocation(filePath);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Plays the music file.
 */
public void play() {
    if (player != null && !player.getSourceLocation().equals(null) || !player.getSourceLocation().equals("")) {
        player.play();
    }
}

/**
 * Pauses the music file. 
 */
public void pause() {
    if (player != null && !player.getSourceLocation().equals(null) || !player.getSourceLocation().equals("")) {
        player.pause();
    }
}

/**
 * Stops the music file.
 */
public void stop() {
    if (player != null && !player.getSourceLocation().equals(null) || !player.getSourceLocation().equals("")) {
        player.stop();
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    MusicPlayer player = new MusicPlayer(signlink.findcachedir() + "music.mp3", 0.1f);
    player.play();
    }
}
```

This:

```
player.setCurrentVolume(volume);
```

Doesn't seem to be working, since whatever I set put as the argument, it's still the same, the volume doesn't change. I did ask a question a while back but got no response and I still looking for an answer, the question being; what API can I use for playing an MP3 with volume adjustment and the ability to pause and stop the music, thanks a lot, Sam/

Comment: the volume value is between `0F` and `1.0F`, are you sure you don't set it with wrong values?

Comment: Yeah, I'm setting between 0F and 1.0F, when I set it, I've tried printing the volume value of the player and it's saying 0.0

Comment: Hmm, are you running on an M$ windows machine? so it may be funny, but try to run the `java.exe` as administrator mode, I don't know how does this lib change the volume (application or global system sound)!

Comment: Hmmm... It's setting the volume now but it doesn't actually make a difference to the volume.

Comment: what about compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JLayer is a good choice for playing music (including mp3) files with Java. It can pause, stop, seek tracks, etc. You can get the player to change the line gain/volume with a small modification to one of the JLayer classes - see [Changing volume in Java when using JLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648107/changing-volume-in-java-when-using-jlayer/8765120). There may be another cleaner way of changing the volume with JLayer, but the above works.

Comment: This would change the volume of the output device altogether wouldn't it? I wasn't looking for this as if any sound not from my application would be muted as well... Or am I wrong?